# Scraping the main content only of a web page by JSoup and save to file

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to scrape the main content only of a web page by JSoup and save to a file.

Test web page:
https://netbasal.com/using-the-angular-http-client-in-angular-v15-f4bec3c11926

My test program use java 11, JSoup 1.15.3.

The output is missing:
the title "Using the Angular Http Client in Angular v15",
the source codes (by Github),
the heading "Interceptors in Lazy Loaded Modules".

How to modify the test program to add the missing content?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {
            String dir = "/home/ak/using-the-http-client-v15";
            String filename = "Out";
            Path path = Paths.get(dir + "/" + filename + ".txt");
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://netbasal.com/using-the-angular-http-client-in-angular-v15-f4bec3c11926").get();
            String searchStrings[] = {
                "pw-post-body-paragraph"
            };
            Set<String> tagNameSet = Set.of("span", "p");
            List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String searchString : searchStrings) {
                Elements searchStringElements = doc.getElementsByClass(searchString);
                if (searchStringElements == null)
                    continue;
                if (searchStringElements.hasClass(searchString)) {
                    for (Element e : searchStringElements) {
                        if (tagNameSet.contains(e.tagName())) {
                            String str = e.wholeText() + "\n\n";
                            output.add(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
                int size = output.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    // Java 11 Append mode
                    Files.writeString(path, output.get(i),
                            StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The information on that page is all loaded using JavaScript.  You cannot access the information with JSoup.  Practice on a static web page if you're trying to learn JSoup.  Alternatively, print your document and see what the static web page looks like.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc, ok, Thanks anyway.